# Line Chart in Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

Hi guys just recently learned Google Visualization and am running in trouble. Currently, the chart that is drawn is a little bit small from what I want it to be. when I try to set the `width` and `height` under options, it gives me the desired size but at the cost of dates below are overlapping. Any ideas on how should I work this one out?

[Current size of chart](http://postimage.org/image/qsn843n6p/) | [Desired size of chart](http://postimage.org/image/u230wm5g1/)

Below is my code:

```
var manWindowWidth = $(window).width() / 1.25; // Gives me 1152
var manWindowHeight = $(window).height() / 1.25; // Gives me 668.8

var options = {
    title: 'Performance',
    pointSize: 5,
    //width: manWindowWidth,
    //height: manWindowHeight,
    hAxis: {title: 'Dates', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}},
    vAxis: {title: 'Visits', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}},
    tooltip: {trigger: 'hover'}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had the same problem, I made the text labels slanted (like in your smaller chart). Try setting `hAxis.slantedText` to true and `hAxis.slantedTextAngle` to about 40.

Sample code:

```
var manWindowWidth = $(window).width() / 1.25; // Gives me 1152
var manWindowHeight = $(window).height() / 1.25; // Gives me 668.8

var options = {
    title: 'Performance',
    pointSize: 5,
    width: manWindowWidth,
    height: manWindowHeight,
    hAxis: {title: 'Dates', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 40},
    vAxis: {title: 'Visits', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}},
    tooltip: {trigger: 'hover'}
};
```

Edit: in your first chart, the `hAxis.showTextEvery` is automatically set to 3. Also try playing with that value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, on how to make the text slanted. I was browsing the api refence on how to make that. Thanks.

Comment: by the way, I know this is offtopic but do you know how to fill the area under the line created on the chart just like the one on google analytics' page? I am also looking for it, in case you know how.

Comment: Try using AreaChart instead of LineChart. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart